# Resolve assuming $x$ is real when $x$ is a free variable in a ForAll expression

Tags: assumptions, resolve

I am using *Mathematica* to check whether a function is positive semidefinite. I have come upon an odd situation. Namely, when I input

```
Resolve[ForAll[{x, y}, 0 < y, And @@ Thread[Eigenvalues[D[x^2/y, {{x, y}, 2}]] >= 0]]]
```

the output is simply `True`.

But when I input

```
Resolve[ForAll[y, 0 < y, And @@ Thread[Eigenvalues[D[x^2/y, {{x, y}, 2}]] >= 0]]]
```

the output is `x ∈ Reals`.

Does

```
{x, y}, 0 < y
```

imply in *Mathematica* that `x ∈ Reals`? If so, why?

Comment: I encountered a similar issue with trying to prove a multivariate function is monotonically increasing. Giving the two variables, a constraint on one variable, and the function in the `ForAll`, and asking MMA to `Resolve` the quantifier gave `True` as expected. When I originally gave only one variable (the one with the constraint) as you have done in your second case, MMA told me the omitted variable was in the Reals. My guess is that if you don't include the variable in the quantifier (even though it doesn't matter since it has no constraint), MMA tries to apply a condition to it for `True`.

Comment: Your code uses a comparison (>) with x. 
The complex numbers are not an ordered field. You cannot use (>) with them. So when you do use (>) with a number, it is assumed you mean it is a real number.

Comment: Look at the result of '(2 (x^2 + y^2))/y^3 >= 0'. You have x in an inequality. If x is an arbitrary complex number, isn't that statement nonsense?

Comment: Hm. I understand that the complex numbers are not an ordered field, so typing '0<y' implies y is real. But when I type '{x, y}, 0 < y', why does that imply x is the same type of object as y? I thought braces {} are for lists which can be collections of different types of objects?

Answer (score 1):

I think the logic for why this happens goes as follows. Start with a simple example:

```
Resolve[ForAll[x, x^2 >= 0]]

(* ==> True *)
```

This can be explained because `Resolve` implicitly assumes that `x` is real because it appears in an inequality. The documentation for [`Resolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Resolve.html) states this.

On the other hand, the inequality isn't changed if we introduce a different variable `y`:

```
Resolve[ForAll[y, x^2 >= 0]]

(* ==> x^2 >= 0 *)
```

Now combine these two simplifications into a single statement, which can have two orders:

```
Resolve[ForAll[x, ForAll[y, x^2 >= 0]]]

(* ==> True *)

Resolve[ForAll[y, ForAll[x, x^2 >= 0]]]

(* ==> True *)
```

In the first line, the inner `ForAll` is removed without changing the inequality, and we're led back to the first case I wrote above. The first  case also kicks in for the inner `ForAll` on the last line, leading to the same result.

But the two consecutive `ForAll` statements are equivalent to

```
Resolve[ForAll[{x, y}, x^2 >= 0]]

(* ==> True *)
```

And here the order in `{x,y}` doesn't matter according to what I said previously.

Now we know that `True` is the "correct" result *without* any additional conditions. But this is a consequence of the step-wise way in which I think `Resolve` eliminates the `ForAll`.

Now the question is whether adding a *condition* such as `0 < y` should change this result. Indeed, the condition is irrelevant when the *unconditional* evaluation already yielded `True`: when something is always true then it is also true under any added conditions.

So the result in my example can be explained because I have implicitly made `x` a real variable by sticking it in an inequality. I believe that essentially the same thing happened in your more complicated example.